# Function never triggered by getElementById().addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to move JavaScript event triggers on the two password fields (to alert the user if they're not equal) from within the form elements to

```
document.getElementById('id_password1').addEventListener('keyUp', checkPass);
document.getElementById('id_password2').addEventListener('keyUp', checkPass);
```

But the function is never triggered (if I change `checkPass` to `checkPass()` the function is called on page-load only, but I don't *think* this means it's being triggered by the listener). There are no errors in the JavaScript console. If I change the ids to something bogus, it gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

(I'm not familiar enough with the Chrome JavaScript inspector, to know if it can help me further.)

It all works properly if the event triggers are directly in the form elements.

Here are the form elements:

```
<p>Password: <input id="id_password1" name="password1" type="password" /></p>
<p>Password confirm: <input id="id_password2" name="password2" type="password" /></p>
```

What am I missing?

```
<HTML><HEAD>
  <TITLE>Create account</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <h1>Create account</h1>

  <form id="user_form" method="post" action="/accounts/register/">

     <p>Username: <input id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" /> <span class="helptext">Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</span></p>
     <p>Password: <input id="id_password1" name="password1" type="password" /></p>
     <p>Password confirm: <input id="id_password2" name="password2" type="password" /></p>

     <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>

     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
  </form>

<script language="JavaScript">
  function checkPass()  {
     var pass1 = document.getElementById('id_password1');
     var pass2 = document.getElementById('id_password2');
     alert("pass1=" + pass1.value + ", pass2=" + pass2.value);

     //Check passwords here. Set confirmMessage if bad.
  }

  document.getElementById('id_password1').addEventListener('keyUp', checkPass);
  document.getElementById('id_password2').addEventListener('keyUp', checkPass);

</script>

</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The event is case sensitive. Try "keyup" (all lowercase) instead. See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LfamexLw/

```
function checkPass(){
    alert("keyup");
}

function checkPass2(){
    alert("keyUp");
}

document.getElementById('id_password1').addEventListener('keyup', checkPass);
document.getElementById('id_password1').addEventListener('keyUp', checkPass2);
```

You'll notice checkPass2 never fires.

Comment: That's it! Beyond looking up the list of possible events, is this something I could have figured out in the JavaScript debugger? Like seeing the names of the actually-triggered events? I'm using Chrome.

Comment: (This is indeed a "typo only" question, but it doesn't seem worthy of closing.)

Comment: I don't think so. The reason is that you can of course attach your OWN events. So you could reasonably listen for an event called "keyUp" or "keyUP" etc. If you want to how I figured it out, my rule of thumb is simply to follow this debugging pattern: 1) check and fix any script errors, 2) assume that a magic string is somehow wrong. In this case "onkeyup".

Comment: It isn't case sensitive if defined inside the element... `<div onClick="alert(1);">Click</div>`

Comment: Yes, HTML is not case sensitive, but JS is.

Comment: To clarify for future newbies: `<div onClick="alert(1);">Click</div>` is the same as `<div ONclICk="alert(1);">Click</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code, based on @aquinas' answer, including the full check-the-password function:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
   <TITLE>Create account</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
   <h1>Create account</h1>

   <form id="user_form" method="post" action="/accounts/register/"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> <input id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" /> <span class="helptext">Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</span></p>
      <p><label for="id_password1">Password:</label> <input id="id_password1" name="password1" type="password" /></p>
      <p><label for="id_password2">Password confirmation:</label> <input id="id_password2" name="password2" type="password" /></p>

      <!-- Where checkPass() writes its message -->
      <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>

      <P><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /></P>
   </form>

<script language="JavaScript">
   /*
      From (8/27/2014)
      http://keithscode.com/tutorials/javascript/3-a-simple-javascript-password-validator.html

      Added the "don't print anything if one or both fields are empty" block
    */
   function checkPass()  {
      //Store the password field objects into variables ...
      var pass1 = document.getElementById('id_password1');
      var pass2 = document.getElementById('id_password2');
      //Store the Confimation Message Object ...
      var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
      //Set the colors we will be using ...
      var goodColor = "#66cc66";
      var badColor = "#ff6666";
      //Compare the values in the password field
      //and the confirmation field
      if(pass1.value.length === 0  ||  pass2.value.length === 0)  {
         pass2.style.backgroundColor = null;
         message.style.color = null;
         message.innerHTML = "";
         return;
      }

      if(pass1.value === pass2.value){
         //The passwords match.
         //Set the color to the good color and inform
         //the user that they have entered the correct password
         pass2.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
         message.style.color = goodColor;
         message.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!"
      }else{
         //The passwords do not match.
         //Set the color to the bad color and
         //notify the user.
         pass2.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
         message.style.color = badColor;
         message.innerHTML = "Passwords Do Not Match!"
      }
   }
   document.getElementById('id_password1').addEventListener('keyup', checkPass);
   document.getElementById('id_password2').addEventListener('keyup', checkPass);
   document.getElementById("id_username").focus();
</script>
</BODY></HTML>
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: An improved version: http://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2014/08/28/passwordconfirmjs/